# How to center a square in android studio

Tags: java, android, canvas

I have created a square in android studio, my code for it is below. I don't know how to center it. at the moment I have it starting from an x position of 20 and a y position of 20. How do I make it so that it is centered, do I just have to keep messing around with the coordinates or is there a way to do it exactly?

package com.example.cms0369.somethingelse;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;


public class Draw extends View {
Paint paint = new Paint();
//float startX;
//float startY;
//float stopX;
//float stopY;

public Draw(Context context){
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawLine(20, 20, 200, 20, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(20, 20, 20, 200, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(20, 200, 200, 200, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(200, 200, 200, 20, paint);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```java
int rectSide = ...;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    canvas.drawRect(width/2f - rectSide/2f,
                    height/2f - rectSide/2f,
                    width/2f + rectSide/2f,
                    height/2f + rectSide/2f, paint);
}
```

Comment: @Phill `float` of value 2

Comment: What is `rectSide`?

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré the side length of the square in question I suppose